# Should we used k-means++ instead of k-means?

Tags: algorithm, performance, comparison, cluster-analysis, k-means

The [k-means++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) algorithm helps in two following points of the original k-means algorithm:

1. The original k-means algorithm has the worst case running time of super-polynomial in input size, while k-means++ has claimed to be O(log k).
2. The approximation found can yield a not so satisfactory result with respect to objective function compared to the optimal clustering.

But are there any drawbacks of k-means++? Should we always used it instead of k-means from now on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nobody claims [*k*-means++](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf) runs in O(lg *k*) time; it's solution quality is O(lg *k*)-competitive with the optimal solution. Both *k*-means++ and the common method, called Lloyd's algorithm, are approximations to an NP-hard optimization problem.

I'm not sure what the worst case running time of *k*-means++ is; note that in [Arthur & Vassilvitskii's](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf) original description, steps 2-4 of the algorithm refer to Lloyd's algorithm. They do claim that it works both better and faster in practice because it starts from a better position.

The drawbacks of *k*-means++ are thus:

1. It too can find a suboptimal solution (it's still an approximation).
2. It's not consistently faster than Lloyd's algorithm (see Arthur & Vassilvitskii's tables).
3. It's more complicated than Lloyd's algo.
4. It's relatively new, while Lloyd's has proven it's worth for over 50 years.
5. Better algorithms may exist for specific metric spaces.

That said, if your *k*-means library supports *k*-means++, then by all means try it out.

Comment: just a nitpick. It's log K competitive with optimal, not with Lloyd's. In fact LLoyd's can be arbitrarily bad w.r.t optimal, and has no sane approximation guarantee.

Comment: @Suresh: that's not a nitpick but a thinko on my side. Corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Not your question, but an easy speedup to any kmeans method for large N:

1) first do k-means on a random sample of say sqrt(N) of the points
2) then run full k-means from those centres.

I've found this 5-10 times faster than kmeans++ for N 10000, k 20, with similar results.
How well it works for you will depend on how well a sqrt(N) sample
approximates the whole, as well as on N, dim, k, ninit, delta ...

What are your N (number of data points), dim (number of features), and k ?
The huge range in users' N, dim, k, data noise, metrics ...
not to mention the lack of public benchmarks, make it tough to compare methods.

Added: Python code for kmeans() and kmeanssample() is
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikits-learn-k-means) on SO; comments are welcome.

Comment: The paper, "Refining Initial Points for K-Means Clustering (1998)", by Bradley and Fayyad, describes a similar technique in greater detail: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.44.5872

Comment: Thanks Predictor; have you ever used this ?  (Good ideas get re-discovered, not-so-good ideas too.)

Comment: Have you tried running **k-means++ on a random sample** first, then refining?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, sounds reasonable but no I haven't. Correct me, data sets vary so widely that saying "use variant X on data like Y" is impossible ?

Comment: Well, k-means++ is a more clever way of seeding on pretty much any kind of data than just choosing random objects. So actually there is little reason to not always use k-means++ unless you have a domain specific heuristic for choosing even better seeds.