# kmeans with L1 distance in python

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

Given an NxM feature vectors as numpy matrix. Is there any routine that can cluster it by Kmeans algorithm using L1 distance (Manhattan distance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is offered explicitly in scipy, but you should take a look at the following:

http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/612

Comment: 'The requested URL /scipy/ticket/612 was not found on this server.'

Comment: URL is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one Kmeans algorithm using L1 distance (Manhattan distance). For generality,the feature vector is represented as a list, which is easy to convert to a numpy matrix.

```
    import random
    #Manhattan Distance
    def L1(v1,v2):
      if(len(v1)!=len(v2):
        print “error”
        return -1
      return sum([abs(v1[i]-v2[i]) for i in range(len(v1))])

    # kmeans with L1 distance. 
    # rows refers to the NxM feature vectors
    def kcluster(rows,distance=L1,k=4):# Cited from Programming Collective Intelligence 
        # Determine the minimum and maximum values for each point
        ranges=[(min([row[i] for row in rows]),max([row[i] for row in rows])) for i in range(len(rows[0]))]

        # Create k randomly placed centroids
        clusters=[[random.random( )*(ranges[i][1]-ranges[i][0])+ranges[i][0] for i in range(len(rows[0]))] for j in range(k)]

        lastmatches=None
        for t in range(100):
            print 'Iteration %d' % t
            bestmatches=[[] for i in range(k)]
            # Find which centroid is the closest for each row
            for j in range(len(rows)):
                row=rows[j]
                bestmatch=0
                for i in range(k):
                    d=distance(clusters[i],row)
                    if d<distance(clusters[bestmatch],row): 
                        bestmatch=i
                bestmatches[bestmatch].append(j)
            ## If the results are the same as last time, this is complete
            if bestmatches==lastmatches:
                break
            lastmatches=bestmatches

            # Move the centroids to the average of their members
            for i in range(k):
                avgs=[0.0]*len(rows[0])
                if len(bestmatches[i])>0:
                    for rowid in bestmatches[i]:
                        for m in range(len(rows[rowid])):
                            avgs[m]+=rows[rowid][m]
                    for j in range(len(avgs)):
                        avgs[j]/=len(bestmatches[i])
                    clusters[i]=avgs
        return bestmatches
```

Answer (score 1):

There's code under
[is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikits-learn-k-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikits-learn-k-means),
which uses any of the 20-odd metrics in scipy.spatial.distance. 
See also
[L1-or-L.5-metrics-for-clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11436/l-1-or-l-5-metrics-for-clustering); could you comment on your results with L1 vs. L2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pyclustering](https://pyclustering.github.io/docs/0.9.0/html/da/d22/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1kmeans_1_1kmeans.html). Here you can find an implementation of k-means that can be configured to use the L1 distance. But you have to convert the numpy array into a list.

how to install pyclustering

```
pip3 install pyclustering
```

a code snippet copied from [pyclustering](https://pyclustering.github.io/docs/0.9.0/html/da/d22/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1kmeans_1_1kmeans.html)

```
pip3 install pyclustering

from pyclustering.cluster.kmeans import kmeans, kmeans_visualizer
from pyclustering.cluster.center_initializer import kmeans_plusplus_initializer
from pyclustering.samples.definitions import FCPS_SAMPLES
from pyclustering.utils import read_sample

sample = read_sample(FCPS_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_TWO_DIAMONDS)

manhattan_metric = distance_metric(type_metric.MANHATTAN)
kmeans_instance = kmeans(sample, initial_centers, metric=manhattan_metric)
kmeans_instance.process()
```

Comment: Another alternative is [kmedoids](https://pypi.org/project/kmedoids/)