# Clustering of 3D points

Tags: cluster-analysis, spatial, hierarchical-clustering

I have a large dataset of around 20 million points (x,y,z) in a 3-dimensional space. I know these points are organized in dense regions, but that these regions vary in size. I think a standard unsupervised 3D clustering should solve my problem.

Since I can't estimate the number of clusters a priori, I tried using k-means with a wide range for k, but it is slow and also, I would have to estimate how significant each k-partition is.
Basically, my question is: how can I extract the most significant partition of my points into clusters?

Answer (score 5):

k-means is probably not the best alhorithm for such data.

DBSCAN should be closer to your intuition of *dense* regions.

Try on a sample first, then figure out how to scale up.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me from the above if you're going to use k-means or not, but if you are, you should be following the responses from the post below which shows how to measure variance of the clusters.

[Calculating the percentage of variance measure for k-means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645895/calculating-the-percentage-of-variance-measure-for-k-means)

Additionally, you can get a good fit using 'the elbow method' by trying 2 to 15 k sized clusters. See the answer from Amro for the process on this.

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea in this case is to use 3 different clusterings, along each dimension. That might speed things up.

So you find clusters along X axis (project all the points down to X axis) and then continue to form sub clusters along the Y axis and then along the Z axis.

I think 1-D k-means can be solved very efficiently using dynamic programming http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0025556473900072.