# is it necessary/appropriate to calculate tf-idf as a preprocessing for LDA (Gensim)?

Tags: python, tf-idf, lda, gensim

I am new to the LDA and I have three questions. I would like to classify my text (tags) with the LDA. First I filter the words, which have been used only by one user, machine tags, tags containing only digits and tags with the frequency less than 3.
Then, I calculate the amount of topics with the Elbow method and there I get the memory error (this will be the third question). So the amount of topics suggested by the Elbow method is 8 (I have filtered some more tags to overcome the memory issue but I would need to apply it to bigger datasets in the future).

1. Should I use tf-idf as a preprocessing step for the LDA? Or if I filter the "useless" tags before it doesn't make sense? I think I don't understand what is going on exactly in the LDA.

   ```
   dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
   corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
   tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
   corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]
   lda = ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus_tfidf, id2word=dictionary, alpha = 0.1, num_topics=8)
   corpus_lda = lda[corpus_tfidf]
   ```
2. Does it make sense to validate the topics quality with the LSI? As I understand the LSI is a method for dimensionality reduction, so I use it to apply K-Means and to see if the 8 clusters of the topics actually look like clusters. But to be honest I don't really understand what exactly I am visualising.

   ```
   lsi = models.LsiModel(corpus_lda, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=2)
   lsi_coord = "file.csv"
   fcoords = codecs.open(lsi_coord,'w','utf-8')
   for vector in lsi[corpus_lda]:
       if len(vector) != 2:
       continue
       fcoords.writelines("%6.12f\t%6.12f\n" % (vector[0][1],vector[1][1]))
   fcoords.close()
   num_topics = 8
   X = np.loadtxt(lsi_coord, delimiter="\t")
   my_kmeans = KMeans(num_topics).fit(X)
   k_means_labels = my_kmeans.labels_
   k_means_cluster_centers = my_kmeans.cluster_centers_
   colors = ['b','g','r','c','m','y','k','greenyellow']
   for k, col in zip(range(num_topics), colors):
   my_members = k_means_labels == k
   plt.scatter(X[my_members, 0], X[my_members, 1], s=30, c=colors[k], zorder=10)
   cluster_center = k_means_cluster_centers[k]
   plt.scatter(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], marker='x', s=30, linewidths=3, color='r', zorder=10)
   plt.title('K-means clustering')
   plt.show()
   ```
3. Memory issues. I am trying to create a matrix which has values for every unique term. So if the term is not in the document it gets zero. So it is a sparse matrix, because I have around 1300 unique terms and every document has about 5. And the memory issue arise at the converting to np.array. I guess I have to optimize the matrix somehow.

   ```
    # creating term-by-document matrix
   Y = []
   for z in corpus_lda:
       Y1=[]
       temp_dict={}
       for g in z:
           temp_dict.update({g[0]:g[1]})
        counter=0
        while counter < len(dictionary.keys()):
           if counter in temp_dict.keys():
               Y1.append(temp_dict[counter])
           else:
               Y1.append(0)
           counter+=1
       Y.append(Y1)
   Y = np.array(Y)
   ```

The following code I took from here : [Calculating the percentage of variance measure for k-means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645895/calculating-the-percentage-of-variance-measure-for-k-means)

```
    K = range(1,30) # amount of clusters 
    KM = [kmeans(Y,k) for k in K] 
    KM = []
    for k in K:
        KM_result = kmeans(Y,k)
        KM.append(KM_result)

    centroids = [cent for (cent,var) in KM]

    scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
    D_k = [cdist(Y, cent, 'euclidean') for cent in centroids] 
    cIdx = [np.argmin(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
    dist = [np.min(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
    avgWithinSS = [sum(d)/Y.shape[0] for d in dist]  
    kIdx = 8

    # elbow curve
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(K, avgWithinSS, 'b*-')
    ax.plot(K[kIdx], avgWithinSS[kIdx], marker='o', markersize=12, markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='r', markerfacecolor='None')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
    plt.ylabel('Average within-cluster sum of squares')
    plt.title('Elbow for KMeans clustering')
```

Any ideas for any of the questions are highly appreciated!