# Spherical k-means implementation in Python

Tags: python, scipy, k-means

I've been using [scipy's k-means](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html) for quite some time now, and I'm pretty happy about the way it works in terms of usability and efficiency. However, now I want to explore different k-means variants, more specifically, I'd like to apply [spherical k-means](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v50/i10/paper) in some of my problems.

Do you know any good Python implementation (i.e. similar to scipy's k-means) of spherical k-means? If not, how hard would it be to modify scipy's source code to adapt its k-means algorithm to be spherical?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

In spherical k-means, you aim to guarantee that the centers are on the sphere, so you could adjust the algorithm to use the cosine distance, and should additionally normalize the centroids of the final result.

When using the Euclidean distance, I prefer to think of the algorithm as projecting the cluster centers onto the unit sphere in each iteration, i.e., the centers should be normalized after each maximization step.

Indeed, when the centers and data points are both normalized, there is a 1-to-1 relationship between the cosine distance and Euclidean distance

```
|a - b|_2 = 2 * (1 - cos(a,b))
```

The package [jasonlaska/spherecluster](https://github.com/jasonlaska/spherecluster) modifies scikit-learns's `k-means` into `spherical k-means` and also provides another sphere clustering algorithm.

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted, @oriol-nieto

Comment: Shouldn't there be a sqrt in the expression? 


|a - b|_2 = sqrt(2 * (1 - cos(a, b)))

This doesn't change the 1-to-1 relationship pointed out.

Comment: To use jasonlaska/spherecluster as mentioned in the answer, you need a legacy sklearn version == 0.20

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the salient feature in the spherical k-means is the use of the cosine distance, instead of the standard Euclidean metric. With that being said, there is a nice pure numpy/scipy adaptation here on SO in another answer:

[Is it possible to specify your own distance function using Scikits.Learn K-Means Clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikits-learn-k-means)

If that doesn't meet what you are looking for you might want to try [`sklearn.cluster`](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/clustering.html).

Comment: I might be wrong, but the way I understand spherical k-means is that the learned centroids are located in the surface of the hypersphere defined by the standard deviation of your data. You should be able to learn these centroids (and then cluster new data) with your preferred distance measure, not only cosine. In any case, thank you for your answer. This link is actually really interesting.

Comment: @urinieto You may be correct, I have no experience with the spherical K-means. I only assumed it came from a cosine metric based by skimming off the linked paper OP posted. I too, would be interested in a answer that corrects this.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how you do it** if you have polar coordinates on a 3D sphere, **such as (`lat`, `lon`) pairs**:

1. If your coordinates are (`lat`, `lon`) coordinates measured in degrees you can write a function that converts these points into cartesian coordinates, like:

   ```
   def cartesian_encoder(coord, r_E=6371):
       """Convert lat/lon to cartesian points on Earth's surface.

       Input
       -----
           coord : numpy 2darray (size=(N, 2))
           r_E : radius of Earth

       Output
       ------
           out : numpy 2darray (size=(N, 3))
       """
       def _to_rad(deg):
           return deg * np.pi / 180.

       theta = _to_rad(coord[:, 0])  # lat [radians]
       phi = _to_rad(coord[:, 1])    # lon [radians]

       x = r_E * np.cos(phi) * np.cos(theta)
       y = r_E * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
       z = r_E * np.sin(theta)

       return np.concatenate([x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1), z.reshape(-1, 1)], axis=1)
   ```

   If your coordinates are already in radians, just remove the first 5 lines in that function.
2. Install the `spherecluster` package with pip. If your polar data given as rows of (`lat`, `lon`) pairs is called `X` and you want to find 10 cluster in it, the final code for KMeans-clustering spherically will be:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import spherecluster

   X_cart = cartesian_encoder(X)
   kmeans_labels = SphericalKMeans(10).fit_predict(X_cart)
   ```

Comment: I should add, though, that using regular KMeans from `sklearn` probably will give you the same result in 99% of cases. So just transform to cartesian coordinates and cluster them.