# How does "scipy.sparse.issparse" work? It always return "False"

Tags: python, scipy

`scipy.sparse.issparse` is used in this post.

[Is it possible to specify your own distance function using scikit-learn K-Means Clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikits-learn-k-means)

However, I have no idea how it works. I already find the document, which is empty.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.issparse.html

```
from scipy.sparse import issparse

issparse([0, 0, 0])
>> False

issparse([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
>> False
```

It always return `False`. How can I make it return `True`?

Answer (score 6):

`issparse` has nothing to do with how many elements the input has. Rather, `scipy.sparse` defines a number of types optimized for representing sparse matrices, and `issparse` determines whether the input is a sparse matrix object.

```
In [1]: import scipy.sparse

In [2]: scipy.sparse.issparse(scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]]))                          
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

[This page](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/sparse/base.py#L702) defines the spmatrix class

```
class spmatrix(object):
    """ This class provides a base class for all sparse matrices.
```

At the bottom of the page, it defines `issparse` as

```
def isspmatrix(x):
    return isinstance(x, spmatrix)

issparse = isspmatrix
```

So, if I'm reading it correctly, `issparse` is true when `x` is an instance of `spmatrix`.

Answer (score 0):

The function only tests if the variable is a subclass of `spmatrix`. e.g. `il_matrix`  or `dok_matrix`