# K-means Clustering in Opencv & python: Is there any option to cluster in mahalanobis distance?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there any option to cluster in Mahalanobis distance in or can easily be used with the Opencv

```
cv2.kmeans
```

function in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html) shows no arguments in the constructor or otherwise that can change the distance metric.  In fact, visiting the [kmeans.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/kmeans.cpp) source on git, you can see from lines like this that Euclidean distance (i.e., `normL2Sqr`) is hardcoded:

```
const double dist = normL2Sqr(sample, center, dims);
```

If you're open to using <s>sklearn</s> scipy for your kmeans, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means) to see how to specify your own distance metric.