# kmeans with custom distance function or pre-calculated distance matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am using Python 2.7 and need to create k means plot for some data.

The data is not trivial and I need to calculate the distance between the data samples with some custom distance function that I have (this is complex genetic data) and then run k means on it.

I have managed to do this with `h.clustering` in scipy, when calculating the distance function in advance and then passing it instead of the data.

I found [how to run the k-means with sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), but I can not find how to use my own distance function.

I don't have any preference for sklearn, other packages are welcome too.

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify your own distance function using scikit-learn K-Means Clustering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means)