# Classify a list of phrases in two categiries

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, k-means, word2vec

I have a list of phrases which states features of a house.

`l = ["cats allowed", "dogs allowed", "pets allowed" , "24 hour doorman", "24 hour concierge", "24/7 concierge", "24hr doorman", ...]`.

The list has about `20000` words. I want to create cluster of similar words. Here, two clusters will be formed.

`clstr1 = ["cats allowed", "dogs allowed", "pets allowed"]`

`clstr2 = ["24 hour doorman", "24 hour concierge", "24/7 concierge", "24hr doorman"]`

I don't know total number of clusters. Till now, I can only understand that this can be done with `k-means clustering algorithm`. But, for that I have to `vectorize` the words. I am thinking to vectorize words using `pre-trained google word2vec` model and then apply `kmeans` from `scikit learn` with a random number of clusters, `n_clusters = 2000` possibly. Do I have any better way? Using `nltk` or any other method?

Comment: It seems like you are searching for clusters in terms of word meanings / semantics? In that case you need some way to compute distances between words in terms of their semantics. [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) might be a candidate to get these distances. Also, you need to filter out uninteresting terms like a, the, it etc.

Comment: Yes, but can you suggest some tutorial using wordnet. I am new to the field and have only use wordnet lemmetizer once. Thanks, for this.

Comment: Google just found [this](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html). Have a look for `Bug 470` to find out how to compute distances. You then need to pass this distance function into kmeans, which seems to be possible with nltk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means