# scikit-learn kmeans clustering text with jaccard distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, text-classification

I'm trying to use sklearn to cluster some tweets as a dictionary
I have 25 initial centroids id (tweet id)
I wrote it in my own functions, BUT I don't know how to implement it with sklearn

```
# {845512:'tweet id 845512', 543115:'tweet id 543115', ...}
# initial_centroids = [845512, 546318, 84632, ...] - 25 centroids

NOTE: tweets_vec <= I need to make it by jaccard_distance
tweets_vec = Is the jaccard distance matrix (it may be wrong, i dont know)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=25, init=initial_seeds).fit(tweets_vec)
```

I made a 2D matrix in which there are jaccard distances. I don't know how to fix init in kmeans method. it errors that's not ndarray

what exactly should I  pass to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means where you could find your solution in the top answer.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I may state the problem vaguely. I'll edit it to make it more clearer.

Answer (score -1):

if within kmeans you pass `init=initial_centroids`, then `initial_centroids` must have shape `clusters x features`. If you are using only one feature you might have to reshape your array, try:

```
init_cent_array = np.asarray(initial_centroids).reshape(-1,len(initial_centroids))
```

and pass it as `init` argument in kmeans. Hope this helps.