# Seed selection strategies for K-means

Tags: random, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I wonder what kind of seed selection methods I can apply to K-means algorithm. Google search wasn't that helpful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at two-pass k-means: k-means a random sample, use those centres as seeds for the lot. See [should-we-use-k-means++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706678/should-we-used-k-means-instead-of-k-means).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seeds depend on the domain. For example, if your data items are words, your seeds should be the most frequent words. Otherwise, you could cluster a small sample and use that as a seed.

Here is an example of a more sophisticated algorithm:

> Single Pass Seed Selection Algorithm for k-Means. 
>   K. Karteeka Pavan, Allam Appa Rao, A.V. Dattatreya Rao and G.R. Sridhar.
>   Journal of Computer Science 6 (1): 60-66, 2010. [pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=D5EFBEA6EBF2850D5DF059C8E8C14EB7?doi=10.1.1.165.8956&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Google for "supervised" k means clustering & k++ means.... also specify your performance needs ( whats your k? how many input points?)

In general, a few thousand points can easily be clustered w a naive k means algorithm implementation... So I would try that first.

Also, if your not sure what K should be, try MCL clustering first to get a good estimate.